# Linear reward-inaction algorithm for two-armed bandit

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations, expected-value

> Suppose there are two slot-machines. When playing one of them, you win with probability $p$ and while playing the other you win with probability $q$, where $0 < q < p <1$.
>
> A gambler approaches them. He does not know the probabilities of victory for either of slot-machines. However, he has recently read "Theories of Learning" by Hilgard and Bower and has therefore decided to employ the following algorithm from that book:
>
> Suppose $p_n$ is the probability of choosing the first slot-machine on $n$-th pull. Then $p_0 = \frac{1}{2}$ and for $n \geq 1$ $p_{n} = \alpha + (1 - \alpha) p_{n-1}$ if he pulled the lever of the first slot-machine and won, $p_{n} = (1-\alpha)p_{n-1}$ if he pulled the lever of the second slot-machine and won and $p_{n} = p_{n-1}$ otherwise. Here $\alpha \in [0;1]$ is some constant.
>
> What is the expected number of wins the gambler scores if the number of pulls he makes is geometrically distributed with parameter $\gamma$?

What have I tried:

The expected number of wins is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \gamma^n E[q_n]$, where $q_n$ is the probability of winning after $n$-th pull. Because $q_n = p_np + (1 - p_n)q = q + p_n(p - q)$. Thus the expected number of wins is $\frac{q}{1-\gamma} + (p-q)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \gamma^n E[p_n]$. So, all we need is to find $E[p_n]$.

For $p_n$ we have the following recurrence:

$$p_0 = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$p_n = \begin{cases}  \alpha + (1 - \alpha) p_{n-1} & \quad \text{ with probability } p_{n-1}p \\ (1-\alpha)p_{n-1}  & \quad \text{ with probability } (1 - p_{n-1})q \\ p_{n-1}  & \quad \text{ with probability } 1 - q - p_{n-1}(p - q) \end{cases}$$

However, because this recurrence is non-linear it can not be easily translated into recurrence for expectations. And here I am stuck.

Comment: It seems that when one considers $E(e^{-\beta p_n})$ the recursion relation you can build for that is more tractable. However, you can still recover the expectation values you want by taking derivatives in $\beta$. That being said I have 2 questions: 1) shouldn't the probabilities on the RHS of the recurrence be depending only on the previously established probabilities? $p_{n-1}p$ instead of $p_{n}p$ and so on... I would expect this to be a causal chain, ie the bandit adjusts the probablity after the n-th pull- in other words he performs pull $P_1$ with probabilities set by $p_0$ (continued)

Comment: and then updates to probabilities set by $p_1$ etc... This being true 2) should it not be true that $E(p_n)=(1+\alpha(p-q))E(p_{n-1})-\alpha(p-q)E(p_{n-1}^2)$ ??

Comment: @DionsaurEgg, 1) Yes, it should. There was a typo in the formula. Now I have corrected it. 2) Yes, your formula is correct. However, I doubt, that finding $E(p_{n-1}^2)$ is any easier.